Multi trip routing using Google OR tools constrained on a maximum total unique orders picked
I want to create a routing model with 1 vehicle and with each node having time windows. I know the time it takes to reach each node from every other node.
For each node, the vehicle picks up items that belong to certain orders. I want to put an additional constraint that says after picking up $N$ unique orders (corresponding to bins in the vehicle), go back to the depot, empty the picked items and continue the route with the remaining locations to be visited. The code that I have tried counts the number of unique orders that have been picked but does not force the vehicle to return to the depot and start a new trip.
I am totally new to OR and to Google OR tools.
My objective is to minimize total travel times and tardiness. Should I also maximize the item quantity that is picked from each location along the route?
What I have done so far:
I have added the travel time matrix and also added the time windows along with the order info associated with each location:
data = {
    'travel_times' : times,
    'time_windows' : [(0, 365), (0, 365), (0, 365), (0, 365), (0, 365), (0, 365), (0, 365), (0, 365), (0, 365), (0, 365), (0, 365), (0, 365), (0, 365)], #lets assume the time windows are the same for now
    'depot' : 0,
    'num_vehicles' : 1,
    'num_locations' : times.shape[0],
    'order_info': [[],
    [1],
    [2],
    [3],
    [4],
    [1],
    [4],
    [3],
    [5],
    [2],
    [5],
    [2],
    [3],
],
'cluster_size' : 3
}

'cluster_size' here denotes the bin size (maximum allowed unique orders that can be picked during a trip).
I have added the travel time callback as below:
def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    return data['travel_times'][from_node][to_node]

# Create the routing index manager
#number of locations
#number of vehicles
#index of depot
manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(data['num_locations'], 
                                       data['num_vehicles'], 
                                       data['depot'])

# Create the routing model
routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
#Add time windows
time = "Time"
routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        5,  # slack of 5 time units
        365,  # vehicle maximum travel time
        False,  # no cumul to zero
        time
    )
time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)
time_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)

I have added the time windows for each node:
# Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(time_windows):
    if location_idx == depot:
        continue
    index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
# Add time window constraints for each vehicle's start node.
depot_idx = depot
for vehicle_id in range(num_vehicles):
    index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
        time_windows[depot_idx][0], time_windows[depot_idx][1]
    )
for i in range(num_vehicles):
    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
        time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i))
    )
    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
         time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))

I added the counter for counting the number of unique orders that have been picked during the trip:
class UniqueItemsCounter:
    def __init__(self, data, manager):
        self.data = data
        self.manager = manager
        self.visited_items = [set() for _ in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles())]

    def __call__(self, from_index, to_index):
        from_node = self.manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = self.manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        if from_node == self.data['depot']:
            self.visited_items = [set() for _ in range(self.manager.num_vehicles())]  # Reset items when at depot
        if to_node == self.data['depot']:
            self.visited_items = [set() for _ in range(self.manager.num_vehicles())]  # Reset items when at depot
        if to_node != self.data['depot']:
            vehicle_id = self.manager.VehicleIndex(from_index)
            self.visited_items[vehicle_id].update(
                self.data['order_info'][to_node])
        return len(self.visited_items[self.manager.VehicleIndex(from_index)])

unique_items_counter = UniqueItemsCounter(data, manager)
unique_items_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(unique_items_counter)
routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
    unique_items_callback_index,
    0,  # no slack
    [data['cluster_size']],  # vehicle capacity
    True,  # start cumul to zero
    'UniqueItems')

And finally solve the problem as follows,
# Solve the problem
search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
    )
solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

This is the solution I get:

Objective: 0
Route for vehicle 0:
0 (Items: []) -> 12 (Items: [3]) -> 11 (Items: [2]) -> 10 (Items: [5]) -> 9 (Items: [2]) -> 8 (Items: [5]) -> 7 (Items: [3]) -> 6 (Items: [4]) -> 5 (Items: [1]) -> 4 (Items: [4]) -> 3 (Items: [3]) -> 1 (Items: [1]) -> 2 (Items: [2]) -> 0
Distance of the route: 181m
Total items picked: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Clearly the route includes all nodes with no returning to depot once the cluster size is reached. How do I achieve going back to the depot to take another trip for the remaining locations?
A few secondary questions I have are:

How to minimize total travel time while maximizing picked quantity (let us say this is another quantity I can track) with the constraint on cluster size?
How do I calculate and print total tardiness for the route given the time windows?


Order Picking isn't really a Capacity Vehicle Routing Problem (CVRP). Each bin has a capacity and if a bin for one order is half-empty, another order can't just use it. More importantly, all items of the same order should be assigned to the same vehicle. That makes in fundamentally different in my experience.
